# Volley postparams array

Tags: android, post, android-volley, parameters

I've got one object containing 2 arrays of integer and I want to past this object in the params of a post request.

```
{
  "ArrayOfInteger1": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "ArrayOfInteger2": [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

I'm struggling with the method "getParams" for hours now, could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

`getParams` wont work in this case because it expects a `Map<String,String>` as the output
You can create a JSON representation of the above object and pass it to `JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, String url, JSONObject yourRequestObject,Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)`
or a `JsonArrayRequest` with similar parameters depending upon what response you expect